# 0% of the site has been indexed. There are 400 items left to index

Tags: search

Drupal core search doesn't re-index the site and it always shows this message.

> 0% of the site has been indexed. There are 453 items left to index.

What settings do I need to change to make Drupal re-index the site properly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [run cron](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron/configuring-cron-jobs-using-the-cron-command).  Because building the search engine can take time, Drupal does it on cron runs (the scheduling system).

First, to make sure everything is OK, run cron manually from `/admin/config/system/cron` to ensure that the search items get indexed.

Then set up cron to run automatically following the instructions in the documentation.